# Add on Domains or Domain Alias

Tags: dns, alias, cname

I am posting this question to get an expert advice as I didn't get it from the Hosting Support Center and searches are not taking me to right direction (I think so).

So I have this website setup at Godaddy (Both hosting + domain ). say `example.org`

Now i needed to register another domain `example.ae` since this Institute is located in Dubai.

What is want is to direct both the domains to the same hosting. What should I use Add on Domains from Cpanel(Deluxe Linux Hosting) or Domain Aliasing. I am familiar with Add on Domains and have done it before (But read somewhere it would affect SEO). 
I am new to domain aliasing. I have attached a screenshot of the Third Party Website (Etisalat) from where I registered .ae domain.

IN which row should I add the fields

> Note : I would like to have the address the user is visiting and just
>   not redirect. Like if you click on `example.ae` I don't want you to
>   redirect to `example.org`. The user must stay in the domain he visited
>   while navigating through the site (Like example.ae/services/)

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

For this you can create redirect example.ae to example.org.

After creating the redirection, use URL masking option in your domain control panel.

So that, the URL never changes to example.org. The URL remains example.ae and serving the datas from example.org.

Hope this post helps your need.